# Delphi - printing XML document by InternetExplorer Ole Object

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, printing, com, ole

I want to print XML document in Delphi, using OleObject. My code:

```
var
  ie : OleVariant;
begin  
  ie := CreateOleObject('InternetExplorer.Application');
  ie.Navigate('doc.xml');
  ShowWindow(frmGlowna.ie.HWND, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
  ie.Visible := True;
  while ie.QueryStatusWB( OLECMDID_PRINT) <> OLECMDF_SUPPORTED + OLECMDF_ENABLED do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  ie.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER,OleVariant(VarAsType($02, varSmallint)), vOut);
  ie.Quit;
  ie := Unassigned;
end;
```

Line:

```
ie.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER,OleVariant(VarAsType($02, varSmallint)), vOut);
```

Execute printing command and wait for finish.

Everything is OK, as long as the program does not run again or run the same program twice at the same time.

I get different errors:

> Catastrophic failure

or

> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like the answer is simple. Don't run the code multiple times simultaneously.

Comment: But I get errors when I close the program and run it again. Then I have to recompile the program again, and only first start the program does not show errors. Each subsequent launch of the program shows the errors .

Comment: We cannot comment on errors whose details we cannot see

Comment: But there is no details... Only "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" or "Catastrophic failure".

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off doing this directly without the need for automation which is after all somewhat flaky

Comment: May be that CreateOleObject attempts to make a new instance of the application, but it should be a singleton? Try to check for an active instance before creation.